# Remapping strings with similar (but slightly differing) substrings to the same result

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"group_code": ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '222', '222','222', '222', '222', '222'],
"ind_code": ['K M trading', 'K.M trad', 'KM trading LL', 'bill payment', 'pays', 'PayMent', 'Payer', 'Rev12','Rev11','13 rev','Rev13','Rev .!','REV 17']
})
```

I wanted to group all the values in the column :
`'K M trading', 'K.M trad', 'KM trading LL'` as `"KM Trading"`.
Can any one plase help me?

I tried the below code, but its not working

```
 def replace_(row):
if 'pay' in row.lower():
    return 'Payment'
if 'rev' in row.lower():
    return 'Rev'
if 'km' in row.lower():
    return 'KM Trade'
else:
return row
df.ind_code = df.ind_code.apply(lambda row : replace_(row))
print(df)
```

Comment: Where is the "grouping" involved?

Comment: are 'K M trading', 'K.M trad', 'KM trading LL' the only possibilities or are there other similar strings ?

Comment: Does `df.ind_code = df.ind_code.str.replace(r'k\.?\s?m\.? .*', 'KM Trading', case=False)` work?

Comment: `'Rev12','Rev11','13 rev','Rev13','Rev .!','REV 17'` all these also come under similar grouping

Comment: @coldspeed I'm always impressed at people with good regex skills :) Not sure if OP is exactly asking this, or if s/he wants something more generalised: how to apply a general rule `km in name.lower()` to a series

Comment: Basically, i m looking to group all . This is my code :

Comment: def replace_(row):
    if 'pay' in row.lower():
        return 'Payment'
    if 'rev' in row.lower():
        return 'Rev'
    return row
df.ind_code = df.ind_code.apply(lambda row : replace_(row))
print(df)

Comment: @coldspeed, i have now edited my question. Hope its more meaningful. Your code works, thats great. But how can i incorporate in my overall logic.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I've tried to generalise as much as possible by editing the question, and also with my answer... let's see...

Comment: @coldspeed it's great!

Comment: @Sheriff Please take a look at the answer and mark it accepted it if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a mapping of regular expressions and call `Series.replace` with the dictionary.

```
mapping = {'pay' : 'Payment', 'rev' : 'Rev', 'km': 'KM Trading'}
for k, v in mapping.items():
    mapping['(?i).*' + r"\.?\s?".join(k) + '.*$'] = mapping.pop(k)

df.ind_code.replace(mapping, regex=True)

0     KM Trading
1     KM Trading
2     KM Trading
3        Payment
4        Payment
5        Payment
6        Payment
7            Rev
8            Rev
9            Rev
10           Rev
11           Rev
12           Rev
Name: ind_code, dtype: object
```

Where

```
print(mapping)

{'(?i).*k\\.?\\s?m.*$': 'KM Trading',
 '(?i).*p\\.?\\s?a\\.?\\s?y.*$': 'Payment',
 '(?i).*r\\.?\\s?e\\.?\\s?v.*$': 'Rev'}
```

Represents case-insensitive replacement with optional periods and spaces between the chars to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the levenshtein distance to calculate a distance between 2 words.
Basically this distance calculates the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) to get from string a to string b

For example you could have your base string 'km trading' and compare it to all other strings and if the distance is below a threshold say 4 then you are pretty sure the string is a variation of 'km trading'.

```
def minimumEditDistance(s1,s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1,s2 = s2,s1
    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for index2,char2 in enumerate(s2):
        newDistances = [index2+1]
        for index1,char1 in enumerate(s1):
            if char1 == char2:
                newDistances.append(distances[index1])
            else:
                newDistances.append(1 + min((distances[index1],
                                             distances[index1+1],
                                             newDistances[-1])))
        distances = newDistances
    return distances[-1]

dist = minimumEditDistance('km trading', 'K.M trad'.lower())
print(dist)
```

this code is taken from Rosetta Code, the algorithm is pretty tricky to understand from pure intuition so I recommend checking some tutorials that explain in depth the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Oren revenge's answer is awesome, here is a hackier solution for your specific cases (though easily extensible):

```
for pair in [('km','KM Trading'), ('pay', 'Payment'), ('rev', 'Rev')]:
    df1.ind_code = df1.ind_code.apply(lambda x: pair[1] if pair[0] in re.sub('\.', '', x.lower()).strip() else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, this might help you.
This code uses the techniques of sequence matcher from "difflib".
For more further details refer "diffllib" in python package documentation.

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib

df = pd.DataFrame({
"group_code": ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '222', '222','222', '222', '222', '222'],
"ind_code": ['K M trading', 'K.M trad', 'KM trading LL', 'bill payment', 'pays', 'PayMent', 'Payer', 'Rev12','Rev11','13 rev','Rev13','Rev .!','REV 17']
})

a = "KM Trading"
ans = []
for val in df['ind_code']:
i = 0
seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a,val)
d = seq.ratio()*100
if d > 60:
ans.append(a)
else:
ans.append(val)

print (ans)
```